# Adding booking meta data to Google Search

Tags: metadata

I can't for the life of me figure out how this company adding this meta data to their Google search.
Does anyone know how to add the data and booking links like the below image?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Comment: It's hardly an SEO question. I'm asking for the code/meta tags used to add this to Google Search. And sure it may help SEO but not the end goal here

Comment: People concerned with SEO will have better shot at such a question, since it's not a W3 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in these search results is what Google defines as "Rich Results" more information can be viewed in Google's [Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/overview) documentation.  Specifically Edgewater Medical center is taking advantage of the [event functionality](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event) to define times and dates.

This can be verified by pasting the page's source in the [Rich Results Test tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), results for this page can be viewed at

https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?utm_campaign=devsite&utm_medium=jsonld&utm_source=event&id=m1ZrUywePCZ_NglFJIjZfg

According to google documentation in order to make this happen you have to follow a few steps:

- Ensure that Googlebot can crawl your event pages (meaning, your pages
  aren't protected by a robots.txt file or robots meta tag).
- Ensure that your server can handle increased crawl rate.
- Make sure you follow the [Google guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event#guidelines).
- Add [structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event#datatypes) to your event pages. Currently, the event experience on Google only supports pages that focus on a single event. We recommend focusing on adding markup to your event posting pages instead of pages that list schedules or multiple events.

An example of such "structured data" for a standard event is shown below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Adventures of Kira and Morrison</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison",
      "startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00-05:00",
      "endDate": "2025-07-21T23:00-05:00",
      "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
      "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventScheduled",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
          "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
          "postalCode": "19019",
          "addressRegion": "PA",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      },
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
       ],
      "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can’t miss performance.",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
        "price": "30",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
        "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
      },
      "performer": {
        "@type": "PerformingGroup",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison"
      },
      "organizer": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
        "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```